# A need for DayOfYear in Log4Net

Tags: c#, log4net

In log4j you could use a date pattern of %d{DDD:HHmmss} where the DDD would be the Day Of Year.  I need to do an equivalent type of pattern in our C# app and I cannot figure out how to get this working.  DataTime ToString doesn't seem to have a formatter for Day Of Year but it does have a property for it call DateTime.DayOfYear.  Anyone know how to get my date pattern set with day of year in log4net?  Any advice is much appreciated.

To be clearer, I am really trying to find a log4net pattern to use in my App.Config that will format the date part of the output in the logfile.  To wit in my App.Config within my appender I have:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%d{MMdd-HHmmss} %-5.5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
</layout>
```

This outputs something like:

```
0319-175824 INFO  Program:33 - Entering Main Method
```

Would like it to output:

```
078-175824 INFO  Program:33 - Entering Main Method
```

Comment: just curious; why do you need 'dayofyear' rather than a date?

Comment: Its their requirement and I think its related to how they do some of their log analysis.  All their apps are in java and produce this type of pattern in the log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own implementation of [DateTimeDateFormatter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.DateFormatter.DateTimeDateFormatter.html) that outputs the format you require.

[FormatDate](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.DateFormatter.AbsoluteTimeDateFormatter.FormatDate.html) looks like the method you would want to override.

Alternatively, you could inject a property containing DateTime.DayOfYear and reference it using the [property](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.LoggingEvent.Properties.html) syntax `%property{doy}`

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["doy"] = DateTime.DayOfYear;
```

Comment: Yes that is true...  Owch I was hoping I was just missing something easy in the format.

Comment: I don't think there will be quick fix solution for this because, as you have found, DateTime.ToString can't output the DayOfYear value. Depending on how you are using log4net using properties may be simpler and give you more flexibility in changing the format. The Formatter solution should offer better performance.

Comment: Interesting. I tried this and needed to correct the line to: log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["doy"] = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear

Comment: I updated it further to deal with the wanted 3 places -> log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["doy"] = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear.ToString("000");